# How to correct the error between $\log(x!)\approx x\sum_{n\leq x}\delta(n)\frac{\log(n)}{n}$, where $\delta(n)$ is the density of primes near x?

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Well assuming that the [Prime Number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) is true, when substituting $\delta(x)$, the density of primes near $x$—which I am being vague of what it means 'cause I don't have enough foundation about the topic—is asymptotic to $\frac{1}{\log(x)}$. Then, when I graphed the difference between $\log(x!)$ & $x\cdot\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{n}$ it seemed linear. What is in my mind is just the harmonic series (which is the [Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)). Then how to go from there.

Note; how did I get the expression in the first place?
$$n!=\prod_{p\leq n}p^{V(n,p)}\approx\prod_{p\leq n}p^{\frac{n}{p}}$$
Where $p$ is a prime and $V(n,p)$ is how many multiples of the prime $p$ in $n!$

My Question "Is $\displaystyle \lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{|\log(N!)-NH_N|}{N}=0$" (Where $H_n$ is $n$-th [Harmonic Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) )

If not then how to correct the error.

Comment: I suggest $\displaystyle\log(n!)= \sum_2^n\log(n)$ what is _not_ an approximation, thus avoids your **error** perfectly. If that's not what you asked for, pls define your XY problem more precisely.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, wt I meant is what to add to the sum to make the error decrease for big x with respect to how big x is. like $\lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{|\log(x!)-x\sum1/n|+E(x)}{x}=0$. Where E(x) is the correction function. And wt I guess $E(x)$ is just zero. But how to prove it? I will edit to make it more clear.

Comment: I just realized that in the last comment, I made a typo I meant to be more clear $$\lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{|\log(N!)-NH_N-E(N)|}{N}=0$$ where is $H_n$ is the harmonic series till $n$.

Comment: $\log(N!) = -\gamma N + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}[N/K-\log(1+N/k)]$